# React native a common Base URL

Tags: react-native, api, base-url

How to maintain a BASE URL common and access anywhere within the project in react native.
Now currently i call api individual & need to simplify code structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an instance of API

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Now call the API's like

```
axios.get(url[, config])
axios.post(url[, data[, config]])
```

This will help in creating a common base URL with common headers and you can import the API anywhere to invoke.

***Edit***

There does exist any method to create an instance of `axios` API. But you can do this to maintain a global base `URL`

```
export const BASE_URL = "https://myurl.com"
axios.get(BASE_URL + "/path")
```

Comment: I'm not using any axios , only using fetch. Using fetch how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Gprakash does this work for you now?

Comment: I have create a in fetch method.
var config = {
    //App Base URL
    BASE_URL :"http://myurl.com/",
    //Version
    VERSION : "v10"
};
export default config;